# Scala: Parsing JSON using the org.fastxml.jackson library

Tags: json, scala

I have written the following program to parse a JSON structure in a streaming fashion.

However this looks very imperative. This is my latest attempt to wrote more idiomatic Scala code but I am not there yet.

I am parsing the following JSON, using the Scala code that follows the JSON snippet. My goal is to shorten the code through the use of more idiomatic scala structures. 
Thanks in advance.

```html
{
    "type": "ImportantIncidentInfo",
    "incidentTimestamp": "2014-05-15T10:09:27.989-05:00",
    "numOfMatches": 4,
    "myReport": {
        "docReports": {
            "part1/.": {
                "path": [
                    "unknown"
                ],
                "myAnalysis": {
                    "matches": [
                        {
                            "id": {
                                "major": 1,
                                "minor": 0
                            },
                            "name": "US SSN",
                            "position": 13,
                            "string": " 636-12-4567 "
                        },
                        {
                            "id": {
                                "major": 3,
                                "minor": 0
                            },
                            "name": "MasterCard Credit Card Number",
                            "position": 35,
                            "string": " 5424-1813-6924-3685 "
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "cleanedUpData": [
                    {
                        "startPosition": 0,
                        "endPosition": 65,
                        "frameContent": ""
                    }
                ],
                "minedMetadata": {
                    "Content-Encoding": "ISO-8859-1",
                    "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
                },
                "deducedMetadata": {
                    "Content-Type": "text/html; iso-8859-1"
                }
            },
            "part2/.": {
                "path": [
                    "unknown"
                ],
                "myAnalysis": {
                    "matches": [
                        {
                            "id": {
                                "major": 1,
                                "minor": 0
                            },
                            "name": "SSN",
                            "position": 3,
                            "string": " 636-12-4567\r"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": {
                                "major": 3,
                                "minor": 0
                            },
                            "name": "MasterCard Credit Card Number",
                            "position": 18,
                            "string": "\n5424-1813-6924-3685\r"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "cleanedUpData": [
                    {
                        "startPosition": 0,
                        "endPosition": 44,
                        "frameContent": ""
                    }
                ],
                "minedMetadata": {
                    "Content-Encoding": "windows-1252",
                    "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=windows-1252"
                },
                "deducedMetadata": {
                    "Content-Type": "text/plain; iso-8859-1"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "whatSetItOffEntry": {
        "action": "Log",
        "component": {
            "type": "aComponent",
            "components": [
                {
                    "type": "PatternComponent",
                    "patterns": [
                        1
                    ],
                    "not": false
                }
            ],
            "not": false
        },
        "ticketInfo": {
            "createIncident": true,
            "tags": [],
            "seeRestrictedIds": [
                {
                    "type": "userGroup",
                    "name": "SiteMasters",
                    "description": "Group for SiteMasters",
                    "masters": [
                        "04fb02a2bc0fba"
                    ],
                    "members": [],
                    "id": "04fade"
                }
            ]
        },
        "letmeknowInfo": {
            "createNotification": true,
            "contactNames": [
                "someguy@gmail.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "seeRestrictedIds": [
        "04fade66c0"
    ],
    "status": "New",
    "timeStamps": [
        "2015-05-15T10:09:27.989-05:00"
    ],
    "count": 1
}
```

---

package mypackage
    import java.io.BufferedReader
    import java.io.FileReader
    import java.io.IOException
    import java.io.InputStream
    import java.util._
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core._
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind._
    import java.util.Properties
    import JacksonStreaming._

```
object JacksonStreaming {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Entered Main")
    try {
      new JacksonStreaming().getNames
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
    }
  }
}

class JacksonStreaming {

  var jsonMapper: ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper()

  var jsonFactory: JsonFactory = new JsonFactory()

  var prop: Properties = new Properties()

  var filePath: String = ""

  val path = Array("myReport", "docReports", "part1/.", "myAnalysis", "matches", "name")

  def getNames() {
    println("Entered getNames")
    var rootNode: JsonNode = null
    try {
      val fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/jsonFormattedModified.json"))
      println("fileReader is: " + fileReader)
      rootNode = jsonMapper.readTree(fileReader)
      println("Return value of jsonMapper.readTree is: " + rootNode)
      findByPath(rootNode)
      val jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(new FileReader("C:/jsonFormattedModified.json"))
      println("JsonParser is: " + jsonParser)
      var pathIndex = 0
      val names = new ArrayList[String]()
      var breakOnClose = false
      while (jsonParser.nextToken() != null) {
        val fieldName = jsonParser.getCurrentName
        if (fieldName == null) {
          //continue
        }
        if (breakOnClose && fieldName == path(path.length - 2)) {
          println("Stopping search at end of node " + fieldName)
          //break
        }
        if (jsonParser.getCurrentToken != JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {
          //continue
        }
        if (pathIndex >= path.length - 1) {
          if (fieldName == path(path.length - 1)) {
            try {
              jsonParser.nextToken()
            } catch {
              case e: IOException => e.printStackTrace()
            }
            var name: String = null
            name = jsonParser.getValueAsString
            if (name == null) {
              throw new RuntimeException("No value exists for field " + fieldName)
            }
            names.add(name)
            println("Found " + fieldName + " value: " + name)
          }
        } else if (fieldName == path(pathIndex)) {
          println("Found node " + path(pathIndex))
          pathIndex += 1
          if (pathIndex >= path.length - 1) {
            println("Looking for names ...")
            breakOnClose = true
            try {
              jsonParser.nextFieldName()
            } catch {
              case e: IOException => e.printStackTrace()
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } catch {
      case e: IOException => e.printStackTrace()
    }
  }

  def findByPath(jn: JsonNode) {
    println("Entered findByPath")
    var matchesNamesNode = jn
    for (i <- 0 until path.length - 1) {
      matchesNamesNode = matchesNamesNode.path(path(i))
    }
    if (matchesNamesNode.isMissingNode) {
      throw new RuntimeException("No node with names found.")
    }
    println("Tree names: " + matchesNamesNode.findValuesAsText("name"))
  }
}
```

Comment: The code is probably too long and unclear for someone to rewrite it for you, which is what you're asking. I'd recommend you try again yourself. For guidance, try to do this with no `var` variables, no `for` loops, no `try/catch` blocks, and reduce the number of `if` statements to the bare minimum.

Comment: No one needs to rewrite it for me. Your recommendation is good and i will attempt the rewrite myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Scala is Expression Oriented, Object oriented and Functional programming language, of course you can write it imperative but for working with JSON I Recommend you to go througt Object Oriented, you can find examples it it's [github repository](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/)

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/

For example I recommend you to write A Scala, classes for All the Json and then for the sub objects like MyReport or whatSetItOffEntry, in the github repo is an example for this type of solution in the repo:

```
package com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.{JsonUnwrapped, JsonProperty, JsonIgnore}
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper


case class Address(address1: Option[String], city: Option[String], state: Option[String])

class NonCreatorPerson
{
  var name: String = _
  @JsonUnwrapped var location: Address = _
  var alias: Option[String] = _
}

case class Person(name: String, @JsonIgnore location: Address, alias: Option[String])
{
  private def this() = this("", Address(None, None, None), None)

  def address1 = location.address1
  private def address1_=(value: Option[String]) {
    setAddressField("address1", value)
  }

  def city = location.city
  private def city_=(value: Option[String]) {
    setAddressField("city", value)
  }

  def state = location.state
  private def state_= (value: Option[String]) {
    setAddressField("state", value)
  }

  private def setAddressField(name: String, value: Option[String])
  {
    val f = location.getClass.getDeclaredField(name)
    f.setAccessible(true)
    f.set(location, value)
  }
}

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class UnwrappedTest extends BaseSpec {

  "mapper" should "handle ignored fields correctly" in {
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

    val p = Person("Snoopy", Address(Some("123 Main St"), Some("Anytown"), Some("WA")), Some("Joe Cool"))
    val json = mapper.writeValueAsString(p)

    // There's some instability in the ordering of keys. Not sure what that's about, but rather than
    // have buggy tests, I'm accepting it for now.
    //    json should (
    //      be === """{"name":"Snoopy","alias":"Joe Cool","city":"Anytown","address1":"123 Main St","state":"WA"}""" or
    //      be === """{"name":"Snoopy","alias":"Joe Cool","state":"WA","address1":"123 Main St","city":"Anytown"}"""
    //    )

    val p2 = mapper.readValue(json, classOf[Person])

    p2 shouldEqual p
  }

  it should "handle JsonUnwrapped for non-creators" in {
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

    val p = new NonCreatorPerson
    p.name = "Snoopy"
    p.location = Address(Some("123 Main St"), Some("Anytown"), Some("WA"))
    p.alias = Some("Joe Cool")

    val json = mapper.writeValueAsString(p)
    val p2 = mapper.readValue(json, classOf[NonCreatorPerson])

    p2.name shouldBe p.name
    p2.location shouldBe p.location
    p2.alias shouldBe p.alias
  }
}
```

Comment: Good direction. I was thinking in terms of case classes, also and you have given me that direction

Comment: I hope that it was just helpfull for you :-)

Comment: I was able to look at your answer just now :). It looks pretty good to me. I am going to take it out for a spin on my system. Can i let you know how it goes? Thanks for your efforts

Comment: Of course, you can I normally use jackson in java, so it will be good to know how it works in scala

Comment: I will review your code tonight, because i have not had a chance to do this so far/ Thanks